# ROBO4J without any LEGO

Tags: java, raspberry-pi, iot

I am trying to learn and use ROBO4J which is purely in java. But in their blogs and videos they talk about using LEGOs for hardware.

I would like to know if this framework support is specific to LEGO or i can expect the same for other hardware as well(rasp pi).

Thanks,
Vijay

Answer (score 0):

From [this bare-bones documentation page](http://www.robo4j.io/p/documentation.html), you can see that the `robo4j-hw-*` module contains support for multiple hardware platforms, including Adafruit and Sparkfun on Raspberry Pi, and also for LEGO platforms as you say.

Their [getting started page](http://www.robo4j.io/2017/04/getting-started-with-robo4j.html) also runs through an example on the Raspberry Pi (specifically using Adafruit).